# Mechanics Question - Thrust in a Rod between train and carriage

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics

I am slightly confused regarding this mechanics question as the worked solution displays thrust as acting towards the centre of the rod whereas I have been taught to see thrust as acting towards the two connected particles.

Also, if the connected objects are decelerating, do you change the direction of the acceleration when finding the answer?

Here is the question:

A train of mass 2500kg pushes a carriage of mass 1100kg along a straight horizontal track. the engine is connected to the carriage by a shunt parallel to the direction of motion. The horizontal resistances to motion of the train and the carriages are RN and 500N respectively.

a)Show that R is 1200N.

b)Find the magnitude of compression in the shunt

c) The driver reduces the driving force produced by the engine to 0 and applies the brakes. The brakes produce a force on the train of magnitude 2000N causing the engine and carriage to decelerate. **Find the magnitude of the thrust in the shunt.**

Initially, the train moved like this, allowing me to work out the compression and R:[image]

So for C, I drew the diagram like this:
[image: Here you can see the thrust is facing outwards]
This gives me :

For the carriage:
500-T=1100a ---> a=(500-T)/1100

For the train:
3200-T=2500a

3200-T=2500*((500-T)/1100)

T= -1621

However, the mark scheme says this but I do not see how it can be correct.
[image] 
Please could someone explain this to me. Thanks!